# counting all occurrences in the last year

Tags: t-sql

I have a question, although I can't really go into specifics.

Will the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tableOuter.Property, (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM table AS tableInner WHERE tableInner.Property = tableOuter.Property)
FROM table AS tableOuter
WHERE tableOuter.DateTime > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
  AND tableOuter.Property IN (
   ...
)
```

Select one instance of each property in the IN clause, together with how often a row with that property occured in the last year?

I just read up on Correlated Subqueries on MSDN, but am not sure if I got it right.

Comment: ... is a list of 25 values, but the returned rows were only 16. Hmm.

Comment: It's probably because of `distinct` it eliminates same rows (and returns only one of them).

Comment: Thanks, I figured it eliminated some rows that didn't make the cut. But otherwise it does what I want it to, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you corrrecly, you want to get all occurences of each `Property` in the last year, am i right?

Then use `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT tableOuter.Property, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM table AS tableOuter
GROUP BY tableOuter.Property
HAVING tableOuter.DateTime > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
AND tableOuter.Property IN ( .... )
```

Comment: I get a SQL Error:
Column 'tableOuter.Property' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The error went away after I put everything in the HAVING clause into a WHERE clause after the FROM.